# Registration Form's onSubmit with Link from React-Router-Dom

Tags: react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom, react-typescript, react-router-component

What I'm trying to achieve is that I want a user to be able to submit a registration only when they follow the correct guidelines, such as having a minimum of 8 characters, etc. I have a button set up with a Link router:

```
//CSS
import "./Register.css"
//LOCAL LIBRARIES
import { VoidFunc, ChangeEventHandlerType, 
FormEventHandlerType } from "./index"
import useSubmit from "../../Hooks/Register/useSubmit";
//EXTERNAL LIBRARIES
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Register = () => {

    {...}

  //Manage Admin
  const [username, password, confirmPassword, handleChange, 
  handleSubmit, placeholder, error, registerUser] = useSubmit()

  return (

      <div className="div-register">

          {...}

        <form className="form-register" 
        onSubmit={handleSubmit as FormEventHandlerType}>

          {...}

              <Link className="link-register" to={registerUser as string}>
                <button className="btn-submit-register">Submit</button>
              </Link>

            {...}

        </form>

      </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

My attempt was to use a useState hook to manage the url destination of the  component so that when the input fields are not filled in properly, the Links "to" property is set to "/register" (keeping the user on the same page they are already on), and when they are, it is set to "/admin" which is the main logged in destination.

I have another .tsx file where I refactored a few elements into one arrow function. The bits I cut out just had conditions like "If the user didnt fill out a field, add an error text to the placeholder for that input field":

```
//LOCAL
import RegisterUser from "../../Components/Register/RegisterUser";
//EXTERNAL
import { useState } from "react";
import {iState, StateType, 
ChangeEventType, FormEventType} from         
"../../Pages/Register/index"

const useSubmit = () =>{

    //Number Check
    let hasNumber = /\d/;  

    //Error
    const [error, setError] = useState<string>("")

    //Is Password valid
    const [registerUser, setRegisterUser] = useState<string>("/register")

    //Placeholder
    const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState<string>("")

    //Manage Admin
    const [state, setState] = useState<StateType>(iState)
    const {username, password, confirmPassword} = state

    const handleChange = (event: ChangeEventType) => {
        //unfinished code
        event.preventDefault()
        const {name, value} = event.target
        setState({...state, [name]: value})
        console.log(state)

    }

    const handleSubmit = (event: FormEventType) => {

        event.preventDefault()

    {...FAILURE CONDITIONS}
    
    //SUCCESS BLOCK
    else {
        setPlaceholder("")
        setError("")
        setRegisterUser("/admin")
    }

    }

  return [username, password, 
  confirmPassword, handleChange, handleSubmit, placeholder, 
  error, registerUser]
}

export default useSubmit;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are really just wanting to navigate to `"/admin"` from the submit handler. For this you should use an imperative navigation instead of the `Link`. (1) the `Link`'s click handler won't wait for the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler to complete, and (2) it certainly can't wait for the `registerUser` state to update.

Use the `useHistory` hook to access the `history` object if you are using `react-router-dom@5` or the `useNavigate` hook to access the `navigate` function if you are using `react-router-dom@6`.

useSubmit

Import and use either `useHistory` ***or*** `useNavigate` hooks, depending on installed version, and invoke in the submit handler on the success logic branch. Remove the `registerUser` state. Return an object instead of an array so destructuring assignment doesn't depend on array indices.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';  // RRDv5
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'; // RRDv6

const useSubmit = () => {
  const history = useHistory();   // RRDv5
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // RRDv6

  // Number Check
  let hasNumber = /\d/;  

  // Error
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");

  // Placeholder
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState<string>("");

  // Manage Admin
  const [state, setState] = useState<StateType>(iState);
  const {username, password, confirmPassword} = state;

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEventType) => {
    // unfinished code
    event.preventDefault()
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      [name]: value
    }));
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event: FormEventType) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    {...FAILURE CONDITIONS}
    
    // SUCCESS BLOCK
    else {
      history.replace("/admin");             // RRDv5
      navigate("/admin", { replace: true }); // RRDv6
    }
  }

  return {
    username,
    password, 
    confirmPassword,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    placeholder, 
    error,
  };
};
```

Register

Remove the `Link` component wrapping the submit button, unnecessary. Use object destructuring assignment from the `useSubmit` hook.

```
const Register = () => {
  ...

  // Manage Admin
  const {
    username,
    password,
    confirmPassword,
    handleChange, 
    handleSubmit,
    placeholder,
    error,
  } = useSubmit();

  return (
    <div className="div-register">   
      ...
      <form
        className="form-register" 
        onSubmit={handleSubmit as FormEventHandlerType}
      >
        ...
        <button className="btn-submit-register">Submit</button>
        ...
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing it this way rather than adding ‘ window.location.href="/admin"‘ to my success block?

Comment: @jmsapps Yes, it won't reload the page, remounting the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a solution. Instead of:

```
<Link className="link-register" to={"/admin"}>
    <button className="btn-submit-register">Submit</button>
</Link>
```

I just added the following to my success block in useSubmit:

```
window.location.href="/admin"
```